# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un código que me escriba lo siguiente?

Tags: python

Necesito obtener este resultado:

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4  
5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8  
9 -- 10 -- 11 -- 12  
13 -- 14 -- 15 -- 16
```

En el programa tengo los valores de filas y columnas, al igual que el largo de los numeros.
Intenté y me sale este resultado:

```
-- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4
-- 5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8
-- 9 -- 10 -- 11 -- 12
-- 13 -- 14 -- 15 -- 16
```

Solo quiero que no me aparezca más el "--" al inicio de cada fila, mi código es este:

```
            i=0
            aux_contador = 0
            aux_contador2 = 0
            while i <= (nombres_archivos+1):
                i+=1
                if aux_contador == int(aux_columnas):
                    
                    wr+='\n'
                    aux_contador = 0
                    aux_contador2=1
                    i-=1
                
                else:  
                    if aux_contador!= int(aux_columnas):
                        wr+=' -- '
                     
                    if i < nombres_archivos and i > 0:
                        wr+='{}'.format(i)
                        #wr+=' -- '
                        aux_contador+=1
                        aux_contador2+=1

                    if i == nombres_archivos :
                        wr+='{}'.format(i)
                        aux_contador+=1
                        aux_contador2+=1
                        
                        break
                
            break
```

[image: Este es el resultado que me da]

Comment: ¿Dónde imprimes en el código que muestras?

Comment: estoy agregándolo a una cadena para poder hacer un archivo de graphviz

Answer (score 1):

Esto genera/imprime la secuencia deseada:

```
for i in range(1, 17, 4):
    linea = f"{i} -- {i+1} -- {i+2} -- {i + 3}"
    print(linea)
```

produce:

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4
5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8
9 -- 10 -- 11 -- 12
13 -- 14 -- 15 -- 16

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Si quisiera que el tamaño de las filas y columnas fuera dinamico, como puedo adaptarlo? es decir, si me dan 49 datos, y las filas son 7 y columnas 7, como puedo imprimir eso?

Comment: @findlesscopy.  Puedes hacer otra pregunta con las nuevas condiciones.